# Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null en input date

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute

Me marca el error cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null pero cabe mencionar que funciona, solo con un date input después si coloco más document.getElementById("fecha_pago"); con otro id por ejemplo document.getElementById("fecha_pago_2"); ya no funcionan los otros inputs date, tengo mi archivo JS al final del DOM

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
/*--==SETEAR MAX DATE EN FECHA PAGO (INPUT DATE)=====--*/
var fecha = new Date();
var dia   = fecha.getDate();
var mes   = fecha.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! TEST
var anio  = fecha.getFullYear();
if(dia < 10) {
  dia = '0' + dia
} 
if( mes < 10) {
  mes = '0' + mes
}

fecha = anio+'-'+mes+'-'+ dia;
inputPagoPB = document.getElementById('fecha_pago');
inputPagoPB.setAttribute('max', fecha);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML? Si getElementById('fecha_pago_2') da null es que no existe el elemento, lo mismo hay algo mal escrito.

Comment: getElementById('fecha_pago_2') no existe solo lo puse de ejemplo, el que si existe es getElementById('fecha_pago') pero lo marca como que no existe, pero funciona y solo con ese, si coloco otro date input y valido este no funciona pero el getElementById('fecha_pago') sigue funcionando

Comment: Insisto, pon el HTML incluyendo los elementos con los que da el error, sino es difícil ver que ocurre.